# "most common after" vs. "second most common after"

Tags: redundancy

I have this sentence:

> iOS is the *second most* commonly used smartphone operating system in the World.

And to name the most common, I write:

> iOS is the *second most* commonly used smartphone operating system in the World *after* Android.

In the second sentence, has *second* become redundant and should have been removed?

Comment: An interesting question, and there are reasonable arguments both ways. In my view it is always a bit odd to make a definitive statement, and then immediately qualify it (indeed, contradict it): **We visited every major city in Europe, except Berlin and Prague.** therefore retaining **second most** is probably the lesser of two awkward constructs, and run the risk of any potential redundancy issues.  I would also hyphenate "second-most".

Comment: In your second example, I'd also put a comma after "World."  Without it, the sentence could be construed to mean Android is first, something else is less commonly used, and iOS is the next one in line, making it two behind Android, and third over all.

Comment: I agree that the insertion of a comma is useful to be specific in your intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct.

The second one is a bit awkward.

Consider this:

**Of all the world's smartphone operating systems, iOS is second only to Android in popularity.**

I do so loathe smartphones and their operating systems. But that's besides the point.

Comment: *Of all the world's smartphone operating systems, iOS is second only to Android in popularity.* This is an elegant way to avoid "second-most ... after", and therefore any risk of redundancy.

Comment: @Cargill: I blush.